# HTTP GET issue when processing JSON returned from REST Spring MVC method

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, get

I have a method in a Spring MVC controller as follows:

```
// Gets a Person via REST.

@RequestMapping(value="/person/{personId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") String personId) {

    logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".getPerson() method called."); 

    Person person = personService.get(Integer.parseInt(personId));
    return new ModelAndView(view,"person", person);        
}
```

The method is working correctly but in the code to process the JSON on the client, I get the following exception:

> Unrecognized field "person" (class libraryApp.model.Person), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: , "personId", "address", "telephone", "books", "name", "email"])

The code is below:

```
// Set request.
        String url = ("http://localhost:8080/Library/rest/person/1");      
        HttpGetRequest httpGetRequest = new HttpGetRequest(url, "GET", ""); 

        // Make request.
        httpGetRequest.get();

// Get response.        
        if (httpGetRequest.getResponseCode() != 200) {                  
            throw new RuntimeException("Get request failed: HTTP error code: " + httpGetRequest.getResponseCode());
        } 
        else {                                      

            // Receive JSON from server and convert to Person.
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            Person person = mapper.readValue(httpGetRequest.getResponse(), Person.class);
            System.out.println("Person:");
            System.out.println(person.toString());
            if (! (person.getBooks().isEmpty())) {
                System.out.println("Books:");
                for (Book book : person.getBooks()) {
                    System.out.println(book.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Person is a simple POJO as follows:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

// Attributes.        
private Integer personId;        
private String name;  
private String address;   
private String telephone;       
private String email;        
private List<Book> books;
```

I am using ModelAndView constructor, `ModelAndView(String viewName, String modelName, Object modelObject)`. So according to the JavaDoc I have to specify a `modelName` but how can I deal with this on the client?

Now I am getting no response on the client from the following if I use a class called Messages in the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            Object obj =  mapper.readValue(httpGetRequest.getResponse(), Object.class);
            if (obj instanceof Messages) {
              Messages m = (Messages) obj;
              for (String s : m.getMessages())
                  System.out.println("Here " + s);


            }
```

Messages is a utility class:

```
public class Messages {

private List<String> messages;

public Messages() { 
    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

With the controller method now:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person/{personId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

@ResponseBody
public String getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") String personId) {

```
logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".getPerson() method called."); 

Person person = personService.get(Integer.parseInt(personId));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Messages m = new Messages();
    m.addMessage("SDGSFGSDFGSDFASDG");
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(m);
    // return mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
}
catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {

        return null;
 }
```

}

Logging the client, I get:

```
Sending Get request: http://localhost:8080/Library/rest/person/1.
```

Receiving response code: 200.
{messages=[SDGSFGSDFGSDFASDG]}

Comment: You need to use ${person} on your client side (JSP or HTML)

Comment: That sounds about right but this is a HTTP GET from a program, so so far I don't know how to do as you suggest in this scenario.

Comment: Have you written scriptlet code on the JSP to read the person?

Comment: There is no JSP. The request is being made by REST.

Comment: I am guessing there is no re-direction in your GET call. You simply want to return an Object of Type `Person`

Comment: That's the problem. I want the server methods to return different objects depending upon validation. hence the use of the `ModelAndView` and not an instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no re-direction from your GET call, try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person/{personId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") String personId) {

    logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".getPerson() method called."); 

    Person person = personService.get(Integer.parseInt(personId));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

}
```

Make sure you `Messages` class is also a POJO

```
public class Messages implements Serializable{

private List<String> messages;

//setters and getters for messages

}
```

Comment: This worked for Person but if I try another class I get no output as per above.

Comment: Make sure `Messages` is a POJO with private fields and appropriate setters and getters as defined by Java standards.

Comment: Your reader is reading `Object` rather than `Messages`. Why is that? You have also used the same controller mapping for `Person` and `Messages`

Comment: I'm trying to do the following: when a method has to return validation messages via REST, I want the method to return Messages object, but if everything is good, it should return a Person.

Comment: In that case you need to have `implements Serializable` for `Messages`

Comment: Yes, I've done that and I know the messages are being received back to the client, but the loop to display then doesn't execute oddly enough. So `if (obj instanceof Messages) {` mustn't be working correctly.

Comment: Put a log for `obj` and check its class/value

Comment: See the addition to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56543/discussion-between-nikhil-talreja-and-mr-morgan).

Comment: Now it seems that Person is being returned as a LinkedHashMap.